# Punctuating a question containing quoted statement

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation

How would I correctly punctuate the following:

*Did you ever say, "Isn't that a cute puppy."*

It's a question, evidenced by "Did you", but "isn't that a cute puppy" is not a question even though it is at the end of a question.

Comment: Why isn't it a question?

Comment: Punctuation is treated prescriptively by some, though not all prescriptivists have the same rules. I've read somewhere that 'British English [whatever that is] allows [whatever that means] double punctuation where necessary to show intended meaning.' I'd use 'Did you ever say, "Isn't that a cute puppy."?' or 'Did you ever say, "Isn't that a cute puppy?"?' for the question variant (which _is_ allowable).

Comment: It allows it, but it is horrifically clunky. Generally you'd expect to see a single question mark, inside the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You have two question here:

- "Did you ever say" is a question which introduces a citation in quotes,
- "Isn't that a cute puppy" is another question.

There all have interrogative words: "Did", "Isn't".

There is a difference with affirmative questions like "So you’re Harry’s cousin?". Without the question mark, it is an affirmation, not a question.

Strictly speaking, this two questions require a question mark. So you should add two question marks. But the usage is to omit the one in the citation:

> Did you ever say: "Isn't that a cute puppy"?